# hover works or not depending on stacking?

Tags: html, css, hover

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/qguq4/19/

Working HTML:

```
<div id="menu">hover me</div>
<div id="firstLayer"></div>
```

Non-working HTML:

```
<div id="firstLayer"></div>
<div id="menu">hover me</div>
```

CSS:

```
#firstLayer {
  background-image:linear-gradient(90deg,red,red);
  background-size: 100% 100%, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100px; 
  min-width:900px; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  top:0;
}

#menu {
 position:absolute; 
 top: 110px; 
 left: 50%;
}

#menu:hover ~ #firstLayer {
 clip: rect(10px,800px,80px,400px);
}
```

Why does the hover effect only work if `#firstLayer` comes after `#menu`?

Comment: I don't see it working at all.

Comment: Have you swaped the two divs? It works for me once I do that. Here's a jsfiddle where i swaped them: http://jsfiddle.net/qguq4/22/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a general sibling combinator. The second element must be preceded by the first.

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators

Comment: I see, then it makes sense it doesn't work. Is there still a way I can maintain the order I want it to be? What I clip is supposed to be the background of what is being hovered..